# What are the dangers/consequences of reducing the SharePoint_Config_log database?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, database-administration

I have used DBCC ShrinkFile on a SharePoint_Config_log database and I'm wondering what the consequences of this action may be?

The log file was growing upwards to >11 GB for an 8GB database and space needed to be freed up. What are some of the consequences for doing this?

I followed this guide: http://www.sharepointboris.net/2008/10/sharepoint-config-database-log-file-too-big-reduce-it/

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no dangers/consequences that are any different from any other Microsoft SQL Server database, which is what the Sharepoint databases are. You won't lose any data by performing a shrink operation.